# pandas.concat function doesnt work correctly with my def, how can I improve that?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas Series as name of; a,b,c,....m
I want to concate with

```
newage = pd.DataFrame([])
newage = pd.concat((newage,a),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)

# This way doesn't have any problem, I can take fully filled series, bun If I try this def

defage = pd.DataFrame([])
listofage = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m]

def agefill (listofage):
    defage = pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in listofage:
        defage = pd.concat((defage,i),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
    return defage

# When the running this def --> agefill(listofage)
# If I want print this I can print (print(agefill(listofage))) but I cant take series with train_df['defage'] = defage doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

````
listofage = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m]

def agefill (listofage):
    defage = pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in listofage:
        
        defage = pd.concat((defage,i),axis=0,ignore_index=False,sort=True)
    
    return defage
        
print(agefill (listofage))


train_data["defage"] = agefill (listofage)
train_data```

###It is working properly.
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).